# How to show Navigationbar 'TitleView' Common for all pages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigationbar, titleview

I have added `TitleView` in `MainPage` to show on `Navigationbar` but it shows only for `MainPage` when I navigate to some other page `Navigationbar` displaying empty.

Below code I have in **`MainPage.xaml`** file

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
<RelativeLayout  HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
    <Image Source="bell.png"  HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" x:Name="imgBell"
           RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
         Type=RelativeToParent,
         Property=Height,
         Factor=0.018,Constant=10}">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding GetStaffAnnouncementCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>

        <Label  FontSize="10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="2"    TextColor="Red"
                HeightRequest="22" WidthRequest="23" x:Name="labelText">
    </Frame>

</RelativeLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

[image]

When I click on *bell icon* and move to second page `TitleView` not displaying at all

[image]

How can I display `TitleView` common for all pages?

Comment: Have you placed the Whole Title view code inside second page as well?

Comment: To reduce this effort you can create one common control of Title view and just use that in all other pages, but you have to use <NavigationPage.TitleView> <Your control with code of title view/></NavigationPage.TitleView> in every page where you want to display title view.

Comment: Yeah this can be done but I just want to avoid to have TitleView in all pages.

Comment: You can also create common ContentPage with title view and use only that common page where ever required, as you are any how declaring page in your xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a demo about your needs.
There is GIF.

[image]

You could Write a custom page inherits from 'ContentPage' and add toolbar item to it.

**Update**

I achieve it with `DependencyService`, If you want to know more details about how to achieve DependencyService, you could refer to this blog and my code.
https://www.xamboy.com/2018/03/08/adding-badge-to-toolbaritem-in-xamarin-forms/

There is code that used `DependencyService`.

Custom `ToolbarPage`

```
 public class ToolbarPage : ContentPage
{
    public ToolbarItem toolbarItem;
    public static int item;
    public ToolbarPage()
    {

        // public ToolbarItem(string name, string icon, Action activated, ToolbarItemOrder order = ToolbarItemOrder.Default, int priority = 0);
         toolbarItem =new ToolbarItem();
        toolbarItem.Icon = "ring2.png";

        toolbarItem.Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary;
       // toolbarItem.Text = item+"";
        toolbarItem.Priority = 0;

        toolbarItem.Clicked += ToolbarItem_Clicked;
        ToolbarItems.Add(toolbarItem);
        if (item >= 1)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IToolbarItemBadgeService>().SetBadge(this, toolbarItem, $"{item}", Color.Red, Color.White);
        }
    }

    private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        item = item + 1;
        DependencyService.Get<IToolbarItemBadgeService>().SetBadge(this, toolbarItem, $"{item}", Color.Red, Color.White);
    }


}
```

Main.cs

```
    public partial class MainPage : ToolbarPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bt1.Text = ToolbarPage.item.ToString();
        bt1.Clicked += async (o, e) =>
        {

           await Navigation.PushAsync(new HelloToolbarInher());
        };
    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        //You must make a delay,
        await  Task.Delay(100);
        bt1.Text = ToolbarPage.item.ToString();
        DependencyService.Get<IToolbarItemBadgeService>().SetBadge(this, toolbarItem, $"{ToolbarPage.item}", Color.Red, Color.White);
    }
 }
```

Do not forget to change **MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:ToolbarPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NaviagationViewDemo"
         x:Class="NaviagationViewDemo.MainPage">

<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Button
        x:Name="bt1"
        Text="click"
        ></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

**There is my new demo.**

https://github.com/851265601/NewNaviagationViewDemo

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your idea is good but writing complex UI is difficult in .cs file.

Comment: @Arvindraja I update my answer, and achieved the UI with dependence service. you could refer to it.